# Dynamically create widgets based on records in a datasource

Tags: google-app-maker

### (Apologies in advance for the poorly worded question.)

Not sure if this is even possible - Have not been able to find any documentation regarding this...

- I have a datasource whose records contain fields of information on certificates.
- For each record in the data source I want to create a label widget on a specified panel. (The panel has been already been created on an app maker page.)

Going to put some pseudo code below to show what I am hoping to achieve:

```
var length = app.datasources.Certificates.items.length;
var records = app.datasources.Certificates.items;

for (var i =0; i <length; i++){
app.pages.A_Edit_Certificate_Requirements.descendants.Panel1.createNewWidget(label,text = records[i].Certificate_Name) 
}
```

.newWidget(type of widget, property of widget to configure) is the pseudo portion.

Anyone know if something like this is even possible?
Reason I am looking to do it via this method is to keep the page as dynamic as possible.

Comment: Have you considered just using the built in grid widget and inserting your label inside the grid cell panel? This will get the same thing accomplished, since the grid widget automatically creates the quantity of children cell panels for your data source items. You can then style the cell panel however you'd like to fit your needs for your label layout.

Comment: Already trying the above. Seems to kind of be working. Just struggling to pull values from the table. Will figure it out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just bind your datasource for the grid widget to 'Certificates', then drag your label into the cell panel and set the value of the label to datasource.item.Certificate_Name. In fact this should be one of your options if your grid is bound to your datasource already and as soon as you select binding on your value attribute it should automatically generate a dropdown with some of the selectable datasource item values. Creating elements on the fly is going to be much more complicated.

Comment: Got this working using the a table and the following code: var results = widget.root.descendants.Table1Body.children._values;

console.log(results[0].descendants.Field.text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to proceed with creating the labels dynamically yourself here would be some sample code to get the same accomplished. In order for this to work your panel datasource would need to be set to 'Certificates' and the code would need to be attached to the panel's onDataLoad event:

```
widget.datasource.items.forEach(function(item) {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.className = 'app-Label';
  node.style.margin = '8px';
  node.textContent = item.Certificate_Name;
  widget.getElement().appendChild(node);
});
```

Comment: Woah that actually somewhat worked. Thanks Markus, gives me something to tinker with.